# Getting error while sending HTTP message using Jmeter : Software caused connection abort: recv failed

Tags: jmeter

I am using Jmeter to publish the message on apache server. I am using ssl (provided certificate in .pfx format) to send the message but getting the error below:

> java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv
>   failed    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.waitForClose(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.security.ssl.HandshakeOutStream.flush(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.sendChangeCipherSpec(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.sendChangeCipherAndFinish(Unknown
>   Source)   at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHelloDone(Unknown
>   Source)   at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown
>   Source)   at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.StringRequestEntity.writeRequest(StringRequestEntity.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod.writeRequestBody(EntityEnclosingMethod.java:499)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2114)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1096)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC3Impl.sample(HTTPHC3Impl.java:265)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1146)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1135)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:434)
>     at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:261)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Question is not clear.

Comment: Add more information, please.

Comment: I am using Jmeter tool to publish one HTTP message to Apache server. But I am not able to post the message. I am getting that error.  Let me know what information you looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The error can be fixed by exclusively using the Java implementation for all HTTP Requests.

This error occurs a lot when using the HTTPClient3.1 implementation, and rarely when using the HTTPClient4 Implementation.

Ensure that all HTTP Requests and HTTP Request Defaults use the Java Implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add HTTP Cookie Manager.